# Symfony2 Memcached - LeaseWeb/LswMemcacheBundle Not work in development mode

Tags: php, symfony, caching, memcached, bundle

Am using Symfony2 in my project and i added this bundle "LeaseWeb/LswMemcacheBundle" to use memcahced , the problem that its work fine for me in the production mode and in development mode show me this error :

> ContextErrorException: Catchable Fatal Error: Argument 3 passed to
>   Lsw\MemcacheBundle\DataCollector\MemcacheDataCollector::addClient()
>   must be an instance of
>   Lsw\MemcacheBundle\Cache\LoggingMemcacheInterface, instance of
>   Lsw\MemcacheBundle\Cache\AntiDogPileMemcache given, called in
>   /home/www/project/app/cache/dev/appDevDebugProjectContainer.php on
>   line 2166 and defined in
>   /home/www/project/vendor/leaseweb/memcache-bundle/Lsw/MemcacheBundle/DataCollector/MemcacheDataCollector.php
>   line 40

And here is my configuration :

```
lsw_memcache:
    session:
        client: default
    clients:
        default:
            hosts:
              - { dsn: localhost, port: 11211 }
```

Any one can help with this ? 
Thank you in advance ...

Comment: Maybe you added the requirement in Composer only for dev mode ?

Comment: Am sorry , i can't get this what do you mean by " adding he requirement in Composer only for dev mode "?!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is solved, its was need libmemcache version 1.0.10 or higher and install last version of memcahced .

Answer (score 0):

I cant see any problem with your configuration.

The error message should not occur with the current version of the bundle.
Which Version of the bundle do you use?

Comment: I used latest version installed by composer Check ...                             require: {    "leaseweb/memcache-bundle": "*" }

Answer (score 0):

This is a reported issue in the symfony bundle, until now is not fixed

https://github.com/LeaseWeb/LswMemcacheBundle/issues/41

Comment: Please consider adding a relevant excerpt of the linked website, since links tend to get invalid over time.